Studying/discussing secular philosophy on Shabbat and their relation to the Torah
I’m curious what the Halacha is regarding studying secular philosophy on Shabbat in order to compare and contrast it to genuine Limmud Torah, for example let’s say someone is discussing Martin Buber’s commentary on the Torah portion, and then the conversation discusses the influence of existentialists, for example Hannah Arendt and  Martin Heidegger, on him and his thought.
There are general halachic concerns with secular discussion on Shabbat and I’m curious how a scenario like this should be treated.

There are halachot of "daber davar", permitted speech on Shabbat, see OC 307:1

Ve’daber davar” (teaches us) that one’s manner of speech on Shabbos
must not be the same as one’s manner of speech on a weekday.
Therefore, it is prohibited to say 'I will do such and such tomorrow'
or 'I will purchase this and this merchandise tomorrow'. Even idle
talk should be curbed. RAMA: People who enjoy hearing stories or the
latest news may speak these things on Shabbos but one who does not
enjoy them may not speak them for the sake of giving pleasure to
someone else.

In other words, one should aim to speak of Torah matters but, if two people enjoy secular subjects, they are allowed to discuss them.
The Mishna Brura adds (:4)

Nonetheless one must take care not to spend excessive amounts of time
in such talk ... because for those not engaged in Torah study during
the week, Shabbat was given primarily as a day of Torah study.

In the end it is a question of balance, between time spent on Torah matters and secular ones, and everyone should find the appropriate mix depending on his situation and what he enjoys discussing.
